# Put same keys from a column in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, key

```
          Name         Adress       Voor        Hoofd         Na     Dish
0   Aisha_BStraat15 BStraat15   BStraat13   BStraat15   AStraat22   Hoofd
1   Aline_AStraat29 AStraat29   AStraat48   AStraat29   AStraat81   Hoofd
2   Alma_BStraat21  BStraat21   AStraat53   BStraat51   BStraat21   Na
9   Bel_BStraat20   BStraat20   AStraat48   BStraat20   AStraat77   Hoofd
10  Berry_AStraat32 AStraat32   BStraat8    AStraat32   AStraat77   Hoofd
47  Math_AStraat77  AStraat77   BStraat58   AStraat57   AStraat77   Na
```

This is a part of my dataframe. It is planning of an event with three dishes named Voor, Hoofd and Na. Every adress prepare one dish, see it in the last cell. In the cells with collnames Voor Hoofd and Na you see the adress where people have to eat the dish.

I want to make a list for every Name within the list the Names who the Name met at the event for expamle: Math_Astraat77 met Berry_AStraat32 and Bel_BStraat20 at the event.

Possible output:

```
[Math_Astraat77, Berry_AStraat32, Bel_BStraat20]
```

my apologies for the bad explanation, First time i used this forum and my English is not very well atm.

Comment: can you show the expected output as an example

Comment: Name                      Adress
47 Mathilde_AStraat77 AStraat77 

AStraat77 is together with Bel_BStraat20 and Berry_AStraat32 so the expected list for AStraat77 is [Mathilde_AStraat77,Bel_Bstraat20, Berry_AStraat32]

Comment: AStraat77 is together with Bel_BStraat20 and Berry_AStraat32 so the expected list for AStraat77 is [Mathilde_AStraat77,Bel_Bstraat20, Berry_AStraat32]

Comment: post the code in good format and edit ur post not as comment please!

Comment: Sorry this is the first time i used this forum

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example read this and dont worry if you are a first timer

Comment: '[Mathilde_AStraat77,Bel_Bstraat20, Berry_AStraat32]' is a possible output for AStraat77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well what do you need it will be in the following way:

```
voor_values = list(df[df.Voor.duplicated(keep=False)].Name.values)
hoofd_values = list(df[df.Hoofd.duplicated(keep=False)].Name.values)
na_values = list(df[df.Na.duplicated(keep=False)].Name.values)

repeated_values = voor_values + hoofd_values + na_values
```

The property `duplicated(keep=False)` return an boolean mask with the repeated values, which is used to retrieve the rows that are repeated on the same column. Then you access to the column that you want, which is `Name`, and obtain the elements in the array using the `values` property.

If the previous idea is correct you can generalize as follows:

```
column_names = ['Voor', 'Hoofd', 'Na']
repeated_values = []
for col_name in column_names:
   repeated_values.append(list(df[df[col_name].duplicated(keep=False)].Name.values))
```

`repeated_values` will have a list of list with Names.

```
for col, names in zip(column_names, repeated_values):
    print(col, names)
```

Comment: Sorry Cristian, this is not what i need. Thank you for the effort. I changed my description

Comment: I updated the code. Check if it's ok. I obtained the same output that you gave as example.

Comment: Your output is a list with al participants at every dish, but i need a list like this:
`
Math_AStraat77 [Math_Astraat77, Berry_AStraat32, Bel_BStraat20]
`
This list containts all the people Math_Astraat77 saw at the event.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see any difference. if you pick a person of the list plus check if that person exists in the other lists you will get the people met.  'Bel_BStraat20' saw [---'Bel_BStraat20'---, 'Berry_AStraat32', 'Math_AStraat77'] + ['Aline_AStraat29', ---'Bel_BStraat20'---],  'Berry_AStraat32' saw ['Bel_BStraat20', ---'Berry_AStraat32'---, 'Math_AStraat77'], 'Math_AStraat77' saw ['Bel_BStraat20', 'Berry_AStraat32', ---'Math_AStraat77'---], 'Aline_AStraat29' saw [---'Aline_AStraat29'---, 'Bel_BStraat20'].